# second derivative question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$, $f''(x)=a$ for all $x \in I$. Show the existance of $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= {a \over 2}x^2 + bx + c $.

So, it's actually just taking the derivative twice. Isn't it?
$f'(x) = ax + b$
$f''(x) = a$

Show the statement isn't necessarily true if $f:A \to \mathbb{R}, f''(x)=a$ for all $x \in A$ when $A$ isn't an interval.

Can you direct me?
I suspect I should give an example such that the derivative doesn't exist. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your approach proves nothing: it just convinces you that the conclusion is plausible.

To give a complete proof, you must know the basic theory of antidifferentiation. You first want to find all functions $g$ such that $g'(x)=a$. The answer is $g(x)=\int a \, dx = ax+b$.
Then you let $g=f'$ and therefore you find $f(x) = \int g(x)\, dx = \frac{a}{2}x^2+bx+c$.

For the second part, I'll give you a hint: choose $A= [0,1] \cup [2,3]$, and glue different parabolas with the same leading coefficient.

Comment: for section #1: Isn't it the same as I did, only in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes, I was on a very slow internet connection, and your answer wan't there when I started writing mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for the second part. Let $A=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$. Define $f$ peicewise as $f(x)=x$ if $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=x+1$ if $x \in (2,3)$. Clearly, $f' = 1$ for all $x \in A$, but $f$ is not of the form $ax +b$. Do you see what is going on here?